# Object oriented design and Database Design Process

Tags: java, database, oop, agile

I'm a little bit confused on how the process of developping a database based application. 
I'm using java language and Relational database.
What's the correct way of looping through the process of developping Object Oriented database based application like "inventory management control".
Developping database schema then doing OOD or Vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I assume you are about to use a traditional RDBMS, from my own experience, it'll be best to first design the database schema: think of all the tables you need to store your information, think of the relations between them (foreign keys).

The next step should be writing the application itself. I assume you're about to use Java, and can benefit from OOP design.

In such a case I strongly recommend  using an ORM technology, like Hibernate, to fulfil the gasp between your OOP app design and RDBMS design. Though it's not obligated, since you can use simple JDBC approach.

From my experience, developing this way is much less time consuming than first design your high level OOP application, and then trying to fit a DB schema to it, because usually messing with DB is more time-expensive than with high level OOP abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different approaches possible and they each have their merits and downside.

If you follow the ORM approach and use a tool like Hibernate you can hide much of the database implementation. You would proceed with your OOD and the database schema would drop out of that. ORMs like Hibernate even do the schema generation for you (this is very helpful in testing as you can create an in-memory database on the fly for your tests).

The advantages of this approach is that you can focus on the OOD and work with 'thin slices' where the database schema is generated as you progress. This fits in well with the agile approach.

The downside with the ORM approach is that it may not result in an optimised database schema. For example, the performance of your database schema may not be as good as if you had focused more on the schema design.

If you decide to focus on the database design you can spend time optimising it for performance and other non-functional requirements (like scalability and auditing). The downside with this approach is that it may restrict the way you do OOD in your code and it may be more difficult to work in the iterative fashion preferred by agile.